# How to search and replace a string while preserving variable part of the string in vim

Tags: bash, vim

I want to search and replace a string in vim with preserving the variable part of string. for example:

```
StringA("variable1")
StringA("variable2")
StringA("variable3")
StringA("variable4")
```

replace this with:

```
StringA("variable1", new_constant_string)
StringA("variable2", new_constant_string)
StringA("variable3", new_constant_string)
StringA("variable4", new_constant_string)
```

What i want to do is search for

```
s/StringA(*)
```

and replace it with

```
        s/StringA(*)/StringA(*, new_constant_string)
```

where (*= variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4 and is preserved)

Comment: Do you want to preserve the double quotes or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also filter the lines using `g` and then apply `s`

```
:g/StringA(/s/)$/, new_constant_string)/
```

- `:g/StringA(/` all lines containing `StringA(`
- `s/)$/, new_constant_string)/` substitute `)` at end of line with `, new_constant_string)`

  - remove `$` is there can be characters after `)` in the line

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
:%s/StringA(".\{-}"/&, new_constant_string
```